# Просаживается fps в unity когда выделяешь определённый объект?

Tags: unity3d

Когда я выделяю один из объектов (чтобы посмотреть его скорость, т.к. на нём есть Rigidbody), то в редакторе unity, при запуске, fps падает до 20, хотя обычно 200+. Это наверно баг unity, потому что от выделения объекта в иерархии врятли что-то меняется. Может у кого-то был подобный баг, и удалось как-то пофиксить. Версия unity 2020.3.0f1. В билде такого наверно ни будет, но тестировать не очень удобно.

Comment: скорее всего проблема в быстродействии твоего ПК

Comment: У меня также. :)